# Airflow signals SIGTERM ,using bigquery operator but Task is success

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using  bigquery operator in airflow .Sometimes in the Airflow task logs i receive below error

> "{models.py:1641} ERROR - Received SIGTERM. Terminating subprocesses."

But the task/dag is shown as successful in airflow UI while the underlying sql has not run. 
what could be the reason and how to avoid it.

Comment: Was it you were running query in interactive mode and your slots were full?